# Is it possible to generate RF with a speaker?

Tags: speaker

With my headphones put on I thought what if is possible to generate some induction to my brain with the headphones speakers? some RF right into my mind.

Answer (score 1):

Just about anything will radiate to some extent if you feed it with RF. It's actually more difficult [to make devices not radiate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_compatibility). An antenna is just more efficient. So sure, you can get your headphones to radiate RF simply by connecting them to an RF amplifier.

Unfortunately, this doesn't do anything useful. Put your head between two cell phones, WiFi radios, or Bluetooth headsets. Does anything interesting happen?

Comment: There was apparently a method once (back when it didn't seem odd that the prototype was made with tubes) that put an audio signal on ~ 35 kHz carrier and could play the audio directly into the human nervous system -- or so I've read, but apparently the devices never made it to market and I've never seen a circuit diagram for it.

Answer (score 0):

Speakers work by varying the pressure of the air to generate sound waves (they travel at the speed of sound, and require a medium to travel through). Radio waves are electromagnetic waves (travel at the speed of light, and do not need a transmission medium). Totally different things.

However, it depends what you mean by RF. “Radio frequency” is just electromagnetic waves at any frequency, so it is possible to generate radio waves at 3kHz. Sound waves at this frequency would be audible, but radio waves would not.

Comment: I meant to use the speakers as some kind of antenna